# SubmitChanges Not Working After Deserialization

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I'm trying to save object as per code below but no error is thrown, the record is not inserted in the table.

VS 2017

```
using (MainDataContext db = new MainDataContext(model.ConnectionString))
    {
        Child kid = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Child>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model));
        kid.DTStamp = DateTime.Now;
        db.Child.InsertOnSubmit(kid);
        db.SubmitChanges();
        return new ApiResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK) { ResponseMessage = "Child added successfully", ResponseObject = kid.ChildID };

    }
```

Comment: While you debugging, can u able to see the values available in kid collection ?

Comment: Can u try to use : `db.Child.Add(kid);`

Comment: The kid collection has value. I can't use the .Add() I'm using LinqtoSql. Someone has mentioned to me after Deserialization I might have to look for a way of using Reflection to insert the record, SubmitChanges() might not work.